# What happens if SparkSession is not closed?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What's the difference between the following 2?

```
object Example1 {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        try {
            val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate
            // spark code here
        } finally {
            spark.close
        }
    }
}

object Example2 {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        // spark code here
    }
}
```

I know that SparkSession implements Closeable and it hints that it needs to be closed. However, I can't think of any issues if the SparkSession is just created as in Example2 and never closed directly.

In case of success or failure of the Spark application (and exit from main method), the JVM will terminate and the SparkSession will be gone with it. Is this correct?

IMO: The fact that the SparkSession is a singleton should not make a big difference either.

Comment: Just practical observation w/o closer analysis: if `SparkSession` is not closed in IntelliJ Scala Worksheet, the repeated code execution will fail with invalid link error.

Answer (score 26):

You should **always** close your `SparkSession` when you are done with its use (even if the final outcome were *just* to follow a good practice of giving back what you've been given).

Closing a `SparkSession` may trigger freeing cluster resources that could be given to some other application.

`SparkSession` is a session and as such maintains some resources that consume JVM memory. You can have as many SparkSessions as you want (see [SparkSession.newSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) to create a session afresh) but you don't want them to use memory they should not if you don't use one and hence `close` the one you no longer need.

`SparkSession` is Spark SQL's wrapper around Spark Core's [SparkContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) and so under the covers (as in any Spark application) you'd have cluster resources, i.e. vcores and memory, assigned to your `SparkSession` (through `SparkContext`). That means that as long as your `SparkContext` is in use (using `SparkSession`) the cluster resources won't be assigned to other tasks (not necessarily Spark's but also for other non-Spark applications submitted to the cluster). These cluster resources are yours until you say "I'm done" which translates to...`close`.

If however, after `close`, you simply exit a Spark application, you don't have to think about executing `close` since the resources will be closed automatically anyway. The JVMs for the driver and executors terminate and so does the (heartbeat) connection to the cluster and so eventually the resources are given back to the cluster manager so it can offer them to use by some other application.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but a Spark Application could either succeed or fail. In either case the Spark Application terminates and so does the JVM associated with it. Once the JVM terminates all resources are freed (whether I call close or not). Also, isn't the SparkSession a singleton if I use `getOrCreate()`? What do you mean with "You can have as many SparkSessions as you want"? Thanks!

Comment: Two questions here: 1) regardless of the final outcome - a failure or success - vcores and memory will eventually be freed and available on the cluster, 2) `SparkSession` **may** be a singleton so you can inherit session-specific setup, but you could also do spark.newSession to isolate it from the other sessions.

Answer (score 16):

Both are same!

Spark session's `stop`/`close` eventually calls spark context's `stop`

```
def stop(): Unit = {
  sparkContext.stop()
}

override def close(): Unit = stop()
```

Spark context has run time [shutdown hook](https://www.javatpoint.com/ShutdownHook-thread.) to close the spark context before exiting the JVM. Please find the spark code below for adding shutdown hook while creating the context

```
ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(
  _shutdownHookRef = ShutdownHookManager.SPARK_CONTEXT_SHUTDOWN_PRIORITY) { () =>
  logInfo("Invoking stop() from shutdown hook")
  stop()
}
```

So this will be called irrespective of how JVM exits. If you `stop()` manually, this shutdown hook will be cancelled to avoid duplication

```
def stop(): Unit = {
  if (LiveListenerBus.withinListenerThread.value) {
    throw new SparkException(
      s"Cannot stop SparkContext within listener thread of ${LiveListenerBus.name}")
  }
  // Use the stopping variable to ensure no contention for the stop scenario.
  // Still track the stopped variable for use elsewhere in the code.
  if (!stopped.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
    logInfo("SparkContext already stopped.")
    return
  }
  if (_shutdownHookRef != null) {
    ShutdownHookManager.removeShutdownHook(_shutdownHookRef)
  }
```

Comment: `ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(...)` can be found in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L573

Answer (score 0):

İf you want to see all active sessions; Go jupyter and just clik Running. You will see there all active session then you can click 'shutdown' to close it.

[Here](http://localhost:8888/tree#notebooks) is the cutshort.

[image: ScreenShot of Spark on Jupyter]

Comment: I don't think OP stated that they're using Jupyter notebooks.