# How to manage spark session creation on real projects

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala/spark world. I normally run jobs on local so I use --master as local[k] but how to manage spark session/spark context for whole project in real world applications?

I am looking in-terms of how code structured around sparkSession object creation. For example create a trait for creating sparkSession object and use all over project and also for the unit testing, any better way to do?

Example code would be appreciated.

Comment: This is too broad to answer here. I suggest reading about Spark deployment modes here https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-deployment-environments.html

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I am looking in-terms of how code structured around sparkSession object creation. For example create a trait for creating sparkSession object and use all over project and also for the unit testing Or any better way to do?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I just create a Spark session via `SparkSession.getOrCreate()` in my `main` method and inject it everywhere I need. From `SparkSession` you can get `SparkContext` if you need one.

For tests I create Spark session as a public constant in some helper class and reuse it in all tests. That saves some time when running tests.

Comment: when do you destroy your spark session?

Comment: usually when you are done with your Spark computation

Comment: and it closes automatically when your Java application exits, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44064559/7417402

Answer (score 0):

According to me instead of passing spark session to all the methods and class you create in your project, it is better to create a trait that extends from serializable and create sparksession object and then you could extend that trait on each of the class/object where you are using sparksession instance and it would be more clear and efficient approach.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
trait SparkSessionWrapper extends Serializable {
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession.builder().appName("TestApp").getOrCreate()
  }
object testProcessor extends SparkSessionWrapper{
 val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("path")
}
object testProcessor2 extends SparkSessionWrapper{
 spark.sql("drop table Test.Testtable") 
}
```

If you extend that wrappertrait on each of the object that you create than you would get the sparksession instance on any of the method inside the objects that you are using.
By following the approach approach as we are declaring it as lazy the sparksession instance would get created first time the spark variable is used in your code execution and then it would use the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton accessor ... spark context is singleton so its kinda imperative to have spark session as singleton as well ... just create a singleton wrapper called sparkContextProvider and let it have methods that can get your sparkConf, javaSparkContext, sparkContext, sparkSession, hadoopConfiguration and likes